# How to generate HTML documentation Deno

Tags: javascript, typescript, documentation-generation, deno, typedoc

I heard that Deno had a [built-in documentation generator](https://deno.land/manual/tools/documentation_generator) using the command `deno doc` which I would like to run on my packages.

But it turns out it only generates JSON documentation and another tool must be used to generate HTML documentation.

Is there any existing tool that I can use to generate local HTML files? These are proprietary packages and can't go onto the official deno doc website.

I tried to use [TypeDoc](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc) alongside [`typescript-deno-plugin`](https://github.com/justjavac/typescript-deno-plugin/) to no avail. Is there any solution to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your own instance of https://github.com/denoland/doc_website. It's frontend that can consume JSON output of `deno doc` command.

Comment: How? I cannot find any related documentation.